How can I use prisma when I have a different schema for each user?
I'm developing a SAAS and I'm using Postgres and Prisma. The whole application will be in one database, but I want a different schema for each user. Ex: user_ where  is the user ID.
The thing that I'm stuck in, is: how can I, in my code using prisma, direct the query to the right schema?
All the schema will have the same structure, tables, etc.
I just need a way to direct my query to the right one.
I found ways to do it but defining each schema in the code. But how can I do it in a way that it will be ready for every new user?
All the part of authentication and schema creation for each user is already fine! The point is just with all the selects/inserts/etc.

Why? You could also use row-level security and stick to a single data model. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html

A schema per user is going to cause a lot of design problems. If you ask another question about what problem you're trying to solve with per-user schemas you might get a better solution.
